# Can 2 levels in a factor go missing in a generalised mixed effect model?

Tags: r, categorical-data, effects, levels, mixed

I ran this Generalised mixed effect model

```
glm1bd <- glmer(Abundance ~ Reason + Region + months.since.spill + bareground.cover +
                  litter.cover + Distance.to.nearest.bush + buildings + roads + (1|Site/Session/Point), warrispill,
                control = glmerControl(optimizer= "bobyqa"),
                family=poisson, nAGQ=1)

summary(glm1bd)
```

this was the output I got for the fixed effects.

```
                          Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)               1.434451   0.154745   9.270  < 2e-16 ***
ReasonIllegal Refinery   -0.440155   0.103933  -4.235 2.29e-05 ***
ReasonLeakage and Burst  -0.299258   0.123353  -2.426 0.015265 *  
RegionMainland            0.806694   0.166710   4.839 1.31e-06 ***
months.since.spill24      0.369011   0.158085   2.334 0.019582 *  
months.since.spill36      0.993695   0.150844   6.588 4.47e-11 ***
months.since.spill48      0.780223   0.139148   5.607 2.06e-08 ***
months.since.spill6       0.664436   0.229903   2.890 0.003852 ** 
months.since.spill60      1.009377   0.259291   3.893 9.91e-05 ***
months.since.spillCLU     0.430998   0.212747   2.026 0.042778 *  
bareground.cover          0.003596   0.001370   2.624 0.008692 ** 
litter.cover             -0.006325   0.001808  -3.499 0.000467 ***
Distance.to.nearest.bush -0.003132   0.001457  -2.150 0.031570 *  
buildings                 0.092977   0.039433   2.358 0.018382 *  
roads                     0.152469   0.089965   1.695 0.090121 .
```

The problem now is that month since spill is a factor with 8 levels. The output has shown 6 levels. I understand that one of the levels has been taken by the intercept. I, however, cannot explain the whereabout of the last level. Please, can anyone help me out with this? Thank you.

Comment: Lacking any clue about the real data, I can't thinking of anything other than: how confident are you that all levels are present? `levels(...)` tells you what *may* be present, but `table(..., useNA="ifany")` and/or `unique(...)` will tell you what is *currently* present.